# Помогите решить задачку с while в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, синтаксис

начал изучать python, не пойму что не так с кодом. 
Вот задание:

> use a while True loop (forever loop) to give 4 chances for input of a
>   correct color in a rainbow rainbow = "red orange yellow green blue
>   indigo violet"

Короче говоря за 4 попытки при помощи while найти в строчной переменной цвет, который будет введен через input

```
rainbow = "red orange yellow green blue indigo violet"
tries = 0
while True:
    color = input("Try your color: ")
    tries += 1
    if tries == 4:
        break
    elif color in rainbow == True:
            print ("Correct!")
            break
```

Comment: замените: `color in rainbow == True` --> `color in rainbow.split()`

Comment: что это значит? в курсе еще не было split видимо от меня требуется что-то другое

Comment: @AntonZubochenko, насколько я понимаю, надо разбить строку на массив слов и последовательно сравнивать их с введенным цветом.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский да, но это я еще не проходил. По идее строка color in rainbow == True: должна искать конкретное слово в строчке, но почему то не ищет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нужно заменить выражение `elif color in rainbow == True:` на правильное `elif color in rainbow:`.

Вот почему код из вопроса не работал, хотя на первый взгляд казался правильным:

```
rainbow = "red orange yellow green blue indigo violet"
color = 'red'

# Правильно проверять наличие так:
print(color in rainbow)            # True

# is и == в контексте булевой проверки взаимозаменяемы
print(color in rainbow is True)    # False
print((color in rainbow) is True)  # True
```

---

Меня заинтересовало почему так выходит и погуглив нашел ответ в [этом источнике](http://howtucode.com/python39s-in-__contains__-operator-returns-a-bool-whose-value-is-neither-true-nor-false-113935.html).

Согласно нему, когда мы пишем выражение `color in rainbow is True`, то оно разворачивается в:

```
(color in rainbow) and (rainbow is True)
```

А т.к. `(rainbow is True)` возвращает `False`, то все выражение становится `False`. Но такой проблемы не будет если скобки будут расставлены правильно: `(color in rainbow) is True`.

Ну и конечно, лучше сразу писать правильно:

```
color in rainbow
```

Comment: тогда не ясно как сделать цикличность. программа либо не останавливается на правильном ответе, либо если написать break останавливается на неправильном.

Comment: Замените неправильное выражение `elif color in rainbow == True:` на правильное `elif color in rainbow:`. Если из цикла не нужно сразу выйти, вместо `break` пишите `continue`

Comment: Кстати интересно - почему `color in rainbow == True` выдает `False`? Согласно [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) и [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) это должно выполняться слева направо, т.е. я бы ожидал: `(color in rainbow) == True`...

Comment: @MaxU, меня это тоже сбило с толку :)

Comment: @gil9red, я решил разобраться с [этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/841166/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-1-in-111-true-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-false) ;-)

Comment: @MaxU, выглядит стройно и объясняет этот прикол :)

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно изменить одну строчку:

```
rainbow = "red orange yellow green blue indigo violet"
tries = 0
while True:
    color = input("Try your color: ")
    tries += 1
    if tries == 4:
        break
    elif color in rainbow.split():
            print ("Correct!")
            break
```