# Порядок операций: почему ('1' in '111' == True) возвращает False

Tags: python, синтаксис, приоритет, операции

[В этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/841036/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81-while-%d0%b2-python) встречается код, который в упрощенном виде можно записать так:

```
>>> '1' in '111' == True
False
```

**Почему так происходит?** Ведь согласно таблице ["Operator precedence"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) и `in` и `==` имеют одинаковый приоритет и должно выполняться слева направо.

Т.е. логично предположить что данная конструкция равнозначна:

```
>>> ('1' in '111') == True
True
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Воспользуемся модулем dis, для анализа байткода

```
import dis
dis.dis("'1' in '111' == True")
```

Получим следующий вывод

```
1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('1')
            2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('111')
            4 DUP_TOP
            6 ROT_THREE
            8 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
          10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (True)
          14 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
          16 RETURN_VALUE
      >>  18 ROT_TWO
          20 POP_TOP
          22 RETURN_VALUE
```

Инструкция LOAD_CONST загружает константы в стек, DUP_TOP дублирует значение вершины стека и добавляет его в стек, ROT_THREE поднимает 2 и 3 значения в стеке на 1 позицию вверх, опуская значение вершины стека на позицию 3. Таким образом перед операцией in (смещение 8) в стеке хранятся значения ['111', '1', '111']. Далее возможны два варианта развития событий:

- В случае получения ложного значения переходим на смещение 18 со стеком [False, '111'], ROT_TWO обменяет верхние два значения стека получим стек ['111', False]. POP_TOP удалит '111' и RETURN_VALUE вернет False.
- В случае получения истинного значения после выполнения LOAD_CONST на смещении 12, в стеке будет содержатся следующие значения [True, '111']. Далее происходит операция сравнения значений True и '111', результат которой помещается в стек и затем возвращается.

Получается что  результат выполнения выражения `'1' in '111' == True` будет равен результату выполнения `'1' in '111' and '111' == True`

Comment: отличный ответ, спасибо!

Comment: [Список инструкций `byte code` с краткими пояснениями...](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.Instruction)

Comment: Так баг ли это или фича? Что говорят стандарты? =)

Answer (score 38):

Похоже данная конструкция воспринимается как ["chained comparison"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) наподобие:

```
a < b <= c
```

что эквивалентно

```
a < b and b <= c
```

т.е.

```
'1' in '111' == True
```

будет обрабатываться как:

```
'1' in '111' and '111' == True
```

проверим догадку:

```
>>> '1' in '111' == '111'
True
```

Comment: можно на ast посмотреть

Comment: сравнить `ast.dump(ast.parse("1 < 2 <= 3", 'eval').body[0])` и `ast.dump(ast.parse("1 in 2 == 3", 'eval').body[0])`

Comment: спасибо, выглядит убедительно! Почему бы не оформить ответом?

Comment: я подожду, мне не к спеху ;) Наверняка кому-нибудь пригодиться пример разбора выражения при помощи `ast`

Comment: жаль, что у @jfs так и не дошли руки написать ответ :(